# HTML CHECKBOX: wrote/delete value from div

Tags: javascript, html

I have 9 **checkbox**. When **checkbox:checked** -> value wrote into the div.
I need: when this **checkbox:unchecked** -> value clear from div.
my code:

```
function handleClick(cb) {
  if (cb.checked){
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = cb.value;
    document.getElementById('my').appendChild(p);
  }else{
    enter code here
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/Iaswmn/pen/YJEPPG

Comment: document.getElementById('my').remove(p);

Comment: @Sami this is dont work, cause i have 9 checkbox , and if i choose 2 checked and 1 of them i do unchecked this delete all

Comment: yes, I know but this was just to give you an idea. you can follow any from the below answers which suits you the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an id to the paragraph element you create. You can then remove it on uncheck.

```js
function handleClick(cb) {
  if (cb.checked){
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.id = 'p-' + cb.id
    p.innerHTML = cb.value;
    document.getElementById('my').appendChild(p);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('p-' + cb.id).remove();
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <h3 class="">Аквазона</h3>
  <div class="" data-auto="false">
    <div>

      <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio1" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона, 4 посещения" class="clearText takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
      <label for="Fradio1"><span></span>4 посещения</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio2" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона, 8 посещений" class="clearText   takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
      <label for="Fradio2"><span></span>8 посещений</label><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3 class="newsTitle">Аквазона + бани</h3>
  <div class="newsBody" data-auto="false">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio3" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона+бани, 4 посещения" class="clearText takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
      <label for="Fradio3"><span></span>4 посещения</label>
    </div>
     <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio4" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона+бани, 8 посещений"   class="clearText takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
      <label for="Fradio4"><span></span>8 посещений</label><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h3>
  fsfs
  </h3>
    <div id="my"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How i can do this with textarea?(when keydown in textarea, create <p> and wrote info in real-life type)

Comment: At first, you should reorganize your code a bit. Don't use onclick attribute on inputs, but create an `eventListerner`

Answer (score 1):

**[Working codePen](https://codepen.io/acharki-zakaria/pen/QZOwpZ)**.

You could loop through the checkboxes and add just the checked ones :

```js
function handleClick(cb) {
  document.getElementById('my').innerHTML = "";

  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'), function(cb) {
    if (cb.checked) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML += cb.value;

      document.getElementById('my').appendChild(p);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <h3 class="">Аквазона</h3>
  <div class="" data-auto="false">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio1" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона, 4 посещения" class="clearText takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
    <label for="Fradio1"><span></span>4 посещения</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio2" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона, 8 посещений" class="clearText   takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
    <label for="Fradio2"><span></span>8 посещений</label>
  </div>
  <h3 class="newsTitle">Аквазона + бани</h3>
  <div class="newsBody" data-auto="false">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio3" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона+бани, 4 посещения" class="clearText takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
    <label for="Fradio3"><span></span>4 посещения</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio4" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона+бани, 8 посещений" class="clearText takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
    <label for="Fradio4"><span></span>8 посещений</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>
      fsfs
    </h3>
    <div id="my"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Associate the newly created `p` element together with the checkbox.
then when it gets unchecked you can remove the element that is associated with it

```
var wm = new WeakMap()

function handleClick(cb) {
  if (cb.checked) {
    var p = document.createElement('p')
    p.innerHTML = cb.value
    document.getElementById('my').appendChild(p)
    wm.set(cb, p) // Store the p element
  } else {
    // get the p element associated to this checkbox and remove it
    wm.get(cb).remove()
    // Delete the p tag references to cp
    wm.delete(cb)
  }
}
```

> A WeakMap object is a collection of key/value pairs in which the keys are weakly referenced.  The keys must be objects and the values can be arbitrary values. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

So once you lose the referenser to the checkbox the p element will be removed from the memory as well

Comment: How i can do this with textarea?(when keydown in textarea, create <p> and wrote info in real-life type)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `class` to your dynamically created `p` tag same as your clicked `checkbox` and then compare that on unchecked condition

```js
function handleClick(cb) {
  if (cb.checked){
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.classList.add(cb.getAttribute("id"));
    p.innerHTML = cb.value;
    document.getElementById('my').appendChild(p);
  }else{
    document.getElementsByClassName(cb.getAttribute("id"))[0].remove();
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <h3 class="">Аквазона</h3>
  <div class="" data-auto="false">
    <div>

      <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio1" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона, 4 посещения" class="clearText takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
      <label for="Fradio1"><span></span>4 посещения</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio2" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона, 8 посещений" class="clearText   takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
      <label for="Fradio2"><span></span>8 посещений</label><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3 class="newsTitle">Аквазона + бани</h3>
  <div class="newsBody" data-auto="false">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio3" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона+бани, 4 посещения" class="clearText takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
      <label for="Fradio3"><span></span>4 посещения</label>
    </div>
     <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio4" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона+бани, 8 посещений"   class="clearText takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
      <label for="Fradio4"><span></span>8 посещений</label><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h3>
  fsfs
  </h3>
    <div id="my"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had added a `<p>` tag in the page and changed the js coding.

```js
function handleClick(cb) {
  var a =[1, 2, 3, 4];
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (cb.id.indexOf(a[i]) != -1) {
    var q = i+1;
    var p = document.getElementById(cb.id + q);
    break;
  }}
  if (cb.checked){
    p.innerHTML = cb.value;
  }else{
    p.innerHTML = "";
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <h3 class="">Аквазона</h3>
  <div class="" data-auto="false">
    <div>

      <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio1" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона, 4 посещения" class="clearText takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
      <label for="Fradio1"><span></span>4 посещения</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio2" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона, 8 посещений" class="clearText   takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
      <label for="Fradio2"><span></span>8 посещений</label><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3 class="newsTitle">Аквазона + бани</h3>
  <div class="newsBody" data-auto="false">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio3" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона+бани, 4 посещения" class="clearText takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
      <label for="Fradio3"><span></span>4 посещения</label>
    </div>
     <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Fradio4" name="ActivityType" value="Фристайл, Аквазона+бани, 8 посещений"   class="clearText takeValue" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
      <label for="Fradio4"><span></span>8 посещений</label><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h3>
  fsfs
  <p id="Fradio11"></p>
  <p id="Fradio22"></p>
  <p id="Fradio33"></p>
  <p id="Fradio44"></p>
  </h3>
    <div id="my"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```